# Identityserver4 Revoke One or All tokens

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

In the application, when a user logs out, I would revoke the reference and refresh token for that current session. This is an API and thus other devices can be logged into the application. I want to provide the ability to log out or log out from all devices.

In Identityserver4, when we are logging out, we can use the revocation client to revoke a token:

```cs
var client = new TokenRevocationClient(...);
//var result = await client.RevokeAccessTokenAsync(token);
//var result = await client.RevokeRefreshTokenAsync(token);
```

This, in turn, calls `IReferenceTokenStore.RemoveReferenceTokenAsync(string handle)`.

Now, the question is, how would I revoke *all* tokens for a user? This means that it should call `IReferenceTokenStore.RemoveReferenceTokensAsync(string subjectId, string clientId)` instead.

Comment: I have the exact opposite problem, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904438/revoking-access-token-reference-for-specific-session-in-identityserver4). I would like to revoke a single session/token but have no token available only logoutid in AccountController.LogOut method ... where in IdSrv4 did you call the TokenRevocationClient in your case where you have specific token available when logging out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject an instance of `IIdentityServerInteractionService` and call `RevokeTokensForCurrentSessionAsync()`.

This should lead to calling of `IReferenceTokenStore.RemoveReferenceTokensAsync(string subjectId, string clientId)`.