# Revoking access token (reference) for specific session in IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

I am using `IdentityServer 4` implicit flow with reference tokens.
I made an own implementation of [IPersistedGrantStore](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/release/src/IdentityServer4/Stores/IPersistedGrantStore.cs) which stores grants in a MSSQL database, which works fine.

Now I´d like to revoke a reference token on user logout from the frontend. Because I don´t want to call the revocation endpoint from the frontend I´d like to do it implicitly in the `AccountController.Logout(string logoutId)` method in the IdentityServer (this would also cover a logout from swagger ui).

So I injected an [IIdentityServerInteractionService](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/release/src/IdentityServer4/Services/Interfaces/IIdentityServerInteractionService.cs) into the AccountController, but when I call

```
await _interaction.RevokeTokensForCurrentSessionAsync();
```

in the `LogOut-Method` it revokes ALL tokens for the current subjectid/user and clientid (the method `IPersistedGrantStore.RemoveAllAsync(string subjectId, string clientId)` is called).

But I´d like to just revoke the token of the one specific session (the method is called RevokeTokens`ForCurrentSession`Async after all) which was logged off.

Another approach would be to call `TokenRevocationClient.RevokeAsync` for which I would need the exact token to pass. But in `AccountController.LogOut` I
only have the logoutid and the LogoutRequest (which also does not contain the actual token).

So what is the best solution to implicitly revoke a `specific` access (reference) token on user logout?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hey Thoros, did you got any fix/alternatives for this, I too need this, very badly.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, unfortunately I still don´t have a fix/workaround for this. I´m currently living with this issue which isn´t ideal.